# Bytestring - package version number mismatch

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to run [hafka](https://github.com/tcrayford/hafka/blob/master/Network/Kafka/Request.hs#L14) on my system. And for same element type, `Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString`, haskell throws error due to version number mismatch.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘bytestring-0.10.4.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
                with actual type ‘B.ByteString’
    NB: ‘bytestring-0.10.4.0:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’
          is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
              in package ‘bytestring-0.10.4.0’
        ‘B.ByteString’
          is defined in ‘Data.ByteString.Internal’
              in package ‘bytestring-0.10.6.0’
```

On my system, when i run `ghc-pkg list | grep bytestring`, it shows, 
                                                                        `bytestring-0.10.4.0`.

`ghc` is not using the package versioned `bytestring-0.14.0`. Where does haskell get the actual type version - `bytestring-0.10.6.0`?

I have n't seen any language that checks for type safety across library versions. Why does haskell do that?

Comment: Are you using a sandbox? `ghc-pkg list` won't show you packages installed in the sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you are using a sandbox, in which case you can see which packages are in the sandbox with, for example,

```
cabal exec ghc-pkg list bytestring
```

> I haven't seen any language that checks for type safety across library versions. Why does haskell do that?

There is no a priori reason to believe that the type named `ByteString` in one version of a package is semantically the same as the type with the same name in another version of the package. As a conservative rule, GHC simply doesn't allow mixing. Note that checking that the two types are semantically the same is not restricted to merely looking at the representation of their data; one would also need to compare their type-class instances, an obviously undecidable problem. One might imagine that future GHCs would try to do some more analysis on this front, but it has not been a pressing need -- usually, it is not hard to simply build your package against one and only one version of each dependency.

Comment: i ran the comment... It shows two entries, one in $HOME/.ghc and the other in /opt/ghc/7.8.4/... The exact output is, `/opt/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.4.0
/home/sk/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.6.0
`